# which eclipse to select for mapreduce programs?

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, mapreduce

I am a beginner in map reduce programming.I want to execute my map reduce program using eclipse.I have setup all other required files...There are so many eclipse versions eclipse for JAVA EE,Eclipse for PHP...etc

CAN ANYONE SUGGEST  ME TO SELECT  ECLIPSE THAT IS MORE SUITABLE FOR MAP REDUCE PROGRAMMING?

Comment: You can use any eclipse version. I am using eclipse Juno for more than 3 years

Comment: Please mark this question as answered. You don't want the dreaded tumbleweed badge. :-)

Answer (score 1):

The basic 
http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/mars2
should work

Take a look at https://github.com/hortonworks/hadoop-tutorials/blob/master/Community/T09_Write_And_Run_Your_Own_MapReduce_Java_Program_Poll_Result_Analysis.md